# calling a method thats located in main class from another class

Tags: java, swing, scope

I have a method in the class that holds main called `addNewProduct(String name)` In one of my JPanels i have a JButton that i have an `actionPerformed()` this is in another class called `DesktopGUI`. main creates a copy of `DesktopGUI` and that object makes the frame and all the components. I would like to have a way to call methods in the main class from the `DesktopGUI`.

main class (this is the lines of code that are in question. This is not a full representation of my code. Lines of code may also not be in the order they would be in my real application.)

```
   public List<Product> productList;
    public void addNewProduct(String name){
      Product product = new Product();
      product.setName(name);
      productList.add(product);
    }

    DesktopGUI gui = new DesktopGUI();
    frame = gui.getFrame();
```

In the constructor of `DesktopGUI` it creates and displays the frame.

in a section of code i have

```
SaveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Save Button Pressed");
      System.out.println("Name: "+(String)fileNameField.getText());
      /*the addNewProduct() is located in the class for main*/
      addNewProduct((String)fileNameField.getText());
   }
});
```

I was able to call the class if it was static but then the class productList will always have a size of zero.

given the simple example

```
public class Foo {
   public List<Product> productList;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();

   }
   public void addNewProduct(String name){
      Product product = new Product();
      product.setName(name);
      productList.add(product);
   }
}

class A {
   SaveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          foo.addNewProduct("Hello World");
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have two classes, A and B, and you want B to call `method1()` in A, then B needs a **valid** instance of A to call the method off of. For example...

```
public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B(a); // pass A reference into B

      b.someMethodInB();
   }
}

class A {
   // the method that we're interested in!
   public void method1() {
      System.out.println("method1 in A");
   }
}

class B {
   private A a; //give B a field to hold A's reference

   // Allow B's constructor to accept the A reference
   public B(A a) {
      this.a = a;  // and assign it to a field
   }

   public void someMethodInB() {
      a.method1();   // now B can call A's method
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**
Edits based on your code. Note additions made to make the code snippet **compilable**. Please remember to do this next time:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Foo {
   public List<Product> productList;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo f = new Foo();
      A a = new A(f);

   }

   public void addNewProduct(String name) {
      Product product = new Product();
      product.setName(name);
      productList.add(product);
   }
}

class A {
   private JButton saveButton = new JButton();
   private Foo foo;

   public A(final Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
      saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            foo.addNewProduct("Hello World");
         }
      });
   }
}

class Product {

   public void setName(String name) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

}
```

---

**Edit 3**
I just noticed that you are creating an instance of the GUI inside of your ProductList class. Often it is done the other way around, but if this is the way you want to do it, then if the GUI is not created in the *static* world then pass your reference into the GUI via its constructor by passing in `this`:

```
DesktopGUI gui = new DesktopGUI(this); // Note change
frame = gui.getFrame();
```

Comment: i was thinking about passing the main class into the other class but passing `this` is giving an error. when calling `this` in main is it the scope of main or the scope of the main class.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon: see edits. If you're getting an error, then please simplify your code (similar to what I've done above), and show us your new code and your error/problem.

Comment: I have updated my question based off your example but changed to fit what i'm attempting to do.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon change `A a = new A();` to `A a = new A(new Foo());` and add `public A(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }` to class `A`.

Comment: I see so creating an instance of the foo class will not execute main again correct?

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon: be careful that you only create one Foo instance. Any place you see `new Foo()` you've created a completely new and distinct instance, and changes to one won't be reflected in the other. That's why I've taken pains to pass references around.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating an instance of it but as i only want one instance of the main class as that will be holding all my list objects i don't want any duplicate main classes.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon: and you shouldn't have duplicates. To watch for this, check every time you use the new keyword to create one of your classes.

Comment: would it be ok to save the pointer as a static when a function is holding a pointer of foo()

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon You may should check the `Singleton` pattern. That way you can be sure that there is only one instance of your `Foo` (or `Main`) class.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon: no don't use static anything here, and no don't use the singleton pattern. That's gross overkill which has pitfalls of its own that you don't want and don't need.

Comment: im now able to call the function and able to print some text out showing its being called but if i attempt something like `System.out.println(productList.size());` i get a null pointer exception as if it cant see productList from foo()

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon: I hate to ask for this, but post your original classes to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and give me a link. Let me see what you've got.

Comment: The original code is a lot. This is why i had to simplify down my examples. The main class holds all the data. the main class is calling a class that handles the frame. inside this frame i have parts where tabs are being created and inside the tabs i have buttons and fields. one of the buttons when pressed needs to call a function on main and pass it some data so main can add the new item to its list.

Comment: This program has a loosely coupled GUI as it will also be able to run headless in the command line. I passed the instance of foo into the class that handles the GUI from that where the GUI is creating tabs on command it passes foo into the tab. so each tab has a pointer to foo.

Comment: the tabs are a modified tab with extra functions and close buttons. each tab is implementing an interface i created for tabs.

Comment: OMG i feel so dumb i forgot to put in `productList = new ArrayList<Product>();` sorry everyone. I should have noticed that.